# Does Django ModelForm set unspecified fields to empty?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a Model that looks like:

```
class MyModel(Model):
  name = models.TextField(blank=True, default='')
  bio = models.TextField(blank=True, default='')
```

and a ModelForm that looks like:

```
class MyModelForm(ModelForm):

  class Meta:
      model = MyModel
      fields = ('name', 'bio')
```

When I create/ init my form like this:

```
form = MyModelForm(instance=my_model, data={'bio': 'this is me'})  # where my_model has a name already set
```

then:

```
form.is_valid() # evaluates to true
form.save() # overwrites the name field in my_model and makes it blank!
```

Is this the expected behaviour? How would I change this so that I can ensure that if a field is not specified in the form, but it exists already in the instance that it is not overwritten with an empty string?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note that Django only sets the `name` field to empty because you have set `blank=True`. If the field was required, there would be a validation error instead.

Recently there was a [discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/django-developers/w8UKCLjOMpg/discussion) on the django-developers group about changing this behaviour. The core developers Adrian and Paul were in favour of the current behaviour.

So, if you're going to use model forms for this view with models where you use blank=True, you'll need to include all the model fields in your data dict. You can use the function `model_to_dict` for this.

```
from django.forms.models import model_to_dict
data = model_to_dict(my_model)
data.update({'bio': 'this is me'}) # or data.update(request.POST) 
form = MyModelForm(instance=my_model, data=data)
```

Comment: Thank you for this! Great idea to prevent accidental overwriting of data when I have dynamic modelforms

Comment: @Gromish I did a quick test, and it seemed to work ok for me with a many to many relation. You might be better to ask a new question rather than leaving a comment here because more people will see it.

Answer (score 2):

Providing the `instance` argument to a `ModelForm` is the same as passing `initial`, i.e. they serve the same purpose. What gets save is *always* the `data`. If a field in that dict is empty, then it will be when the model is saved as well.

If you want to maintain the entire state of the model when only dealing with a single field as `data`. Then, try something like the following:

```
data = my_model.__dict__
data['bio'] = request.POST.get('bio')
MyModelForm(instance=my_model, data=data)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass initial data to the form, use initial instead of data

```
MyModelForm(instance=my_model, initial={'bio': 'this is me'})
                               ^
```

[edit]

If you have included the field for name in your form

```
fields = ('name', 'bio')
```

but do not pass any data for "name"

```
data={'bio': 'this is me'}
```

The form field will behave as if the name had been submitted blank.

Which is allowed in your model, so is_valid() will be True

```
name = models.TextField(blank=True, default='')
```

Comment: I'm not trying to pass *initial* data - that's the data i'm trying to validate the form with. (I'm getting it via JSON).